# Supersymmetry in de Sitter space

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, supersymmetry, qft-in-curved-spacetime, de-sitter-spacetime

**Is it possible to construct SUSY theories in de Sitter space?**

I know statement:

> dS superalgebras cannot be constructed unless one constructs actions with matter coupled with
>   the wrong signs for the kinetic terms.

But I don't understand bases of this fact and derivation.

Does existence of of dS-superalgebra depends on dimension of space-time?

Maybe placing SuSY on dS provide some mechanism of SuSY breaking or some impact on cosmology?

Comment: Roughly speaking, we have an accidental isomorphism between AdS spin(3,2) and sp(4) which enables osp, whereas we don't have such luck for dS.

Comment: Could you provide some references?

Comment: See chapter 2 of Introduction to Supersymmetry here: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=XYlXTtu9ARoC&oi=fnd&pg=PP9&dq=related:0fcGsS96tToJ:scholar.google.com/&ots=N1Ktr1yQAz&sig=4C-NSOq03uOpV7u-z8uQspW2URw#v=onepage&q&f=false